# Java histogram in 2 windows from JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, applet, joptionpane, jdialog

this code at the moment allows me to select multiple text files which are then analysed into a bar chart, my problem is when for example 2 files are selected from the JFileChooser the bar charts are opened one after another, so first one will open then when OK is pressed the second will open, i need them both to open simultaneously side by side? If anyone can give me any pointers it would be really appreciated.

```
if ("Analyze Text File".equals(command)) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                String text = sb.toString();
                Map<Integer, Integer> counts = getCounts(text);
                int width = counts.size() * BAR_WIDTH;
                int max = maxCount(counts);
                int height = max * INCREMENT + 100;
                int horizon = height - 25;
                HistogramPanel panel = new HistogramPanel(width, counts, height, horizon);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ray suggested just use `JDialogs`s so you can control the modality. Remember `JDialog` works just like `JFrame`, so if you know how to make a `JFrame`, then `JDialog` should be easy. But with `JDialog` you get to control the modality.

```
for (File file : files) {
    try {
        ...
        HistogramPanel panel = new HistogramPanel(width, counts, height, horizon);
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setModal(false);        <---- very important
        dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        dialog.add(panel);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (...)
}
```

Comment: if this helps you solve your problem, please accept @Ray answer. I'm just trying to help you out with an example since your project is due soon.

Comment: that works great thanks, with JDialogs s is it possible to display content below the histogram for the mean, median, variance and modal length? or will that be best to be displayed in the applet itself?

Comment: It works just like a `JFrame`. Add whatever you need to the `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, like a `JPanel` with your details. `dialog.add(detailPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`. The `HistogramPanel` is already added to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` by default, since you didn't specify a position.

Comment: hi, i need to put it in the actual applet now on a label that i have created called meangraphlength, will i need to add my calculating mean code into the jfilechooser? i have tried to implement it, the code is above..

Comment: What you need to understand about this site is that it isn't a help desk. It's a Q&A site, not just for the question asker, but for all who come across different answers/question. How it works is that you ask a question, you get it answered, you accept an answer. If you have another question, the you post another question. You don't keep asking the same person for help on different topics.

Comment: And don't change posts after they have been answered an accepted. It may invalidate answers.

Comment: the reason why i changed the post for now is because my assignment is due in today and i have had several people copying my assignment which can lead to all of us getting zero for plagarism, i am going to put the code back on by the end of today when the assignment deadline is over..

Comment: and sorry for asking so many questions, thank you very much for your help

Comment: i will post new questions, i didnt know i couldnt keep asking on here, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`JOptionPane` is intended for blocking popups. Things like error messages etc. For your purpose, you should probably rely on modeless `JDialog`s.

Comment: Hi, is there no way to use JOptionPane as i do not have time to research and try implement JDialog s as my assignment is due in a few hours. Sorry i am a beginner so it will take me longer trying to implement JDialog s..